# Cómo puedo arrancar live server con Ratchet?

Tags: php, servidor

Tengo mi aplicativo en localhost usando la librería Ratchet. Cada vez que quiero arrancar mi aplicativo tengo que abrir la consola de comandos y digitar la siguiente directriz:

```
>>php server.php
```

Sin embargo, mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo arrancar mi aplicativo una vez subido al servidor?

Agradezco mucho sus sugerencias.

Comment: De la misma forma. Tenes que ingresar al terminal y ejecutar el mismo comando (_mas o menos... podes agregar que se corra en background asi podes cerrar el terminal y continue ejecutandose_). Hay varios detalles que vas a tener que revisar, como por ejemplo que el servidor tenga el puerto abierto, que no mate el proceso despues de una cierta cantidad de tiempo en ejecución, etc.

Comment: @Marcos Lo que sucede es que yo deseo que arranque automáticamente cuando un usuario haga click en un botón de la pagina ejecutando el "server.php" y corriendo de esta manera el app, no teniendo que hacerlo yo manualmente desde la consola de comandos como lo hago en el localhost.

Comment: En ese caso, salvo lo de entrar al terminal, todo lo demas sigue en pie. Y para ejecutar el comando podes hacer una llamada ajax a un PHP donde hagas algo como `shell_exec('php server.php 2>&1 > server.log');`

Comment: @Marcos Justo estaba pensando en ejecutar el comando shell_exec, pero me podrias indicar qué hace excatmante esta parte de código "2>&1 > server.log" al final de la instrucción? Muchas gracias.

Comment: En linux, `2>&1` indica que la salida estándar de error (`stderr`) sea canalizada a la salida estándar (`stdout`). Luego con `> server.log`, indicamos que todo ese contenido lo guardamos en el archivo `server.log`

Comment: @Marcos En mi página coloco el código PHP que me indicaste shell_exec('php server.php') pero no arranca el servidor, por lo contrario, se queda cargando la página de manera infinita, sin embargo sí puedo arrancarlo desde consola con dicho comando. El tema es que tengo que arrancarlo con código en mi página para que levante automáticamente con la acción del usuario al ingresar. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: @Marcos no será que tengo que implementar en mi servidor un servicio donde se ejecute el archivo server.php y mantenga mi aplicativo escuchando en un puerto determinado? (El server.php abre un puerto y lo mantiene a la escucha)

Comment: Hola Eduardo, probar hacerlo así: `exec("php server.php 2>&1 > server.log &");`